# Updating localStorage at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to integrate an external app with the browser using localStorage.

The javascript running in browser writes a value on localStorage and an external app reads the value from sqlite DB (localstorage) and deletes the record.

The problem is, when I delete the record from localStorage DB, the browser is not updated, for it keeps in memory the old value, already deleted from localStorage. This way, I can't keep up if the value was already read by the external app.

So, how can I make the browser reload the localstorageDB?
If it's not possible, can you suggest an alternative for this issue?

Comment: just don't. you can't even be sure the localstorage is sqlite, maybe some browsers use MSSQL or even csv/xml/struct-to-file/whatever. if it's about communication between your client side javascript and the app running on the same host, just let the app host a small http service and use ajax from JS. or do it the usually more robust way and let both clients just talk to your server.

Comment: Do you have any code to show? .. so we can see what exactly you are calling to delete the localStorage value or key?

Comment: I still don't have the complete app. I Just made the javascript wich writes in localstorage and checked the database. when I alter the data in database or delete, it remains the same in browser. It seems that the values are stored in memory. When I close the browser and open again, the changes I made in DB are loaded to browser localstorage.

Comment: @marionmaiden _"when I delete the record from localStorage DB, the browser is not updated"_ , _"when I alter the data in database or delete, it remains the same in browser"_ How is `localStorage` value deleted ?

Comment: Note what you're trying to do is quite low level and probably not supported by the vendor. What browser are you talking about? Have you thought about a browser extension that interacts with your application (providing an interface via e.g. a network socket, interprocess communication or separate files being monitored)?

Comment: @guest271314 I deleted the data from a sqlite editor and saved the file. Just after closing and reopening the browser I could see the updates I made from browsers inspectors.

Comment: @try-catch-finally, I could access Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome localstorage DBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the browser and external app navigating to the same webpage, using the same browser? If not then this wont work out so well.

What's your external app written in? It might be easier for the external app to create a small web server (i.e. if its written in nodejs you could use express to create a small web server) and your javascript in your browser could do a request to localhost:8080 (or whatever port you bind to) and you can communicate through this mechanism by just doing http requests from browser => external app.

Comment: My external app is a java applet, on which will be converted to an installable for client. It's being made due to future restrictions on browsers for applets.

Comment: This solution you provided was my second option, but I didn't put in the thread to bias the answers. As far as I see, the communication between browsers and apps is tricky as it involves security questions. Anyway, the bounty is yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, WebSQL is [abandoned](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#status-of-this-document).
It is unlikely to be implemented by other browsers, and Chrome is [planning](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=397429#c13) to remove it in future.
Chrome is also free to move / restructure it anytime.

You cannot ask browsers to support every prototype tech forever, while keeping the browsers fast and free.
All browsers cut features.
And deprecated, non-standard features are the first in line.

Macmee's suggestion of having your external program opening a web server make sense.
[There](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) [are](https://github.com/ngallagher/simpleframework) [many](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers) embedded java web servers available,
and cross origin is not a problem when you control the server.

---

As for your issue, perhaps it is the way you read it, because I can't reproduce.
The following code read a count from the database, which I change with an external SQLite browser.

```js
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 1 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction( ( tx ) => {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (count int)');
   tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM LOGS');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (count) VALUES (0)');
});

setInterval( () => {
   db.readTransaction( ( tx ) => {
      tx.executeSql( 'SELECT count FROM LOGS', null, ( tx, rs ) => {
         document.querySelector( 'div' ).textContent = rs.rows[0].count;
      });
   });
}, 500 );
```

```html
Count: <div>?</div>
```

It works. 
Every time I *write* to disk after modifying the count from the db browser, Chrome can read the change immediately.
(Chrome version 47.0.2526.73 beta-m)

So perhaps you can double check that you have actually written your changes to disk in the external program, and that your js is actually reading in a *new* transaction?

(If you stay in same transaction, you will not see new commits, this is what [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) is for.)

Comment: Sheepy thanks for the answer. I wasn't using webSQL, but localstorage, which is specified by w3c (http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). For my surprise, the specification has changed in 2015/11/26, redefining the storage limit issue. The localstorage with variable size may fullfill my needs. I'll have to wait to see when the browsers will uptade this feature. Anyway, I'll close this thread as it confirmed to me that the external app communication is a complex issue for security questions.

Comment: @marionmaiden Sorry I think I remembered the question wrong. But I am very surprised you are willing to read localStorage externally because different browsers do it differently meaning it subjects to even more internal changes (which has happened), unlike WebSQL which must be SQLite.  Browsers have been tightening security, so local server is the most feasible option.